# Web service receive and return XmlDocument

Tags: .net, xml, web-services

I have a web service in .NET 4.0 and trying to call it from web method in .NET 3.5.

**In .NET4.0**

```
    public XmlDocument Method1(System.Xml.XmlDocument InDoc)
    {
        XmlDocument OutDoc;
        // process 

        return OutDoc;
    }
```

**In .NET3.5**

```
    // Method1 turns into 
    System.Xml.Linq.XElement ServiceClient.Method1(System.Xml.Linq.XElement InDoc)
```

Is this the default behavior of such web service, how should configure it so that in the client-side, a XmlDocument is passed to the web service?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass an XmlDocument as the argument and cast the return value to (XmlDocument).

XmlDocument is based on XmlElement.

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't understand. Can you explain further?? Thanks.